# Questions on the usage of "formal" mathematical language

Tags: notation

(First off, my first language is not English, so please tell me if some parts need some clarification/revision)

Hi, I'm new at using the "formal" language of math, so I would like to make sure that my statements are correctly written. I tried to find if these were already answered, but I have no idea how to search for these kinds of questions... (Like, googling "how to use the 'for all' notation for two or more variables in a premise" doesn't work)

1. $ \forall m, n \in \mathbb{N}, \quad \frac{n}{m} \in P $
   (For any natural numbers $m$ and $n$, $\frac{n}{m}$ is a positive number.)

   Do I need to write the premise like " $ \forall m, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $"  or "$ \forall m \in \mathbb{N},  \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $"? Or something like " $ \forall \left (m, n \right) \in \left ( \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{N} \right ) $"?
2. $ \left ( -1 \right ) \left ( -1 \right ) = 1 \in P $

   Is this expression allowed? The operator "$ = $" and the predicate "$ \in $" seem to be.. incompatible? My intuition (which should be ignored in formal mathematics, I know) tells me I should write these two statements separately, e.g.
   $ \left ( -1 \right ) \left ( -1 \right ) = 1  \qquad \therefore \left ( -1 \right ) \left ( -1 \right ) \in P $

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I actually have one more question.
When writing "For any negative integer $a$ and $b$, $ab$ is positive," which is better? ($P$ is the set of all positive real numbers, obviously. No zeros! :D)

"$\forall a,b \; \text{s.t.} \, -a \in P \; \text{and} \, -b \in P, \; ab \in P$"

or

"$\forall a,b, \quad -a \in P \; \text{and} \, -b \in P \Rightarrow ab \in P$"?

Comment: Statements 1. and 2. are fine as is.  Clarity and precision are what is important.

Comment: Your second statement is absolutely unexceptionable. Your first is acceptable if you have previously defined $P$ and if you have specified that for you $\Bbb N$ does not contain $0$, since for many of us it does.

Comment: It depends how formal you want to be. Almost all of the time, readability and precision are the only things that matter. Occasionally it's important to actually work in some fixed logical syntax, but that's rare. Incidentally, your "$\forall m,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$" is actually rather unclear - is $m$ constrained by the "$\in\mathbb{N}$" or not? Either "$\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N}$" or "$\forall m\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$" would do the job though.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Their first statement is totally acceptable, it's just wrong. :P ($0\in\mathbb{N}$ forever!)

Comment: @Noah: :-)  That is certainly my gut response!

Comment: They are both fine, also in general we don't write $(n,m)\in(\mathbb N,\mathbb N)$, but $(n,m)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$. But sure you can write $\forall m,n\in\mathbb N$

Comment: Thank you all. I actually have one more question. (Forgot to write it on the main text :P)
When writing "For any negative integer $a$ and $b$, $ab$ is positive," which is better?

"$\forall a,b \; \text{s.t.} \; -a \in P \; \text{and} \; -b \in P, \; ab \in P$"
or 
"$\forall a,b, \quad -a \in P \; \text{and} \; -b \in P \Rightarrow ab \in P$"?

Comment: Why not just use "$<0$"? Set-theoretic notation isn't always easier to read, and having to remember what "$P$" means (positive? prime? something else?) is a nonzero bit of effort.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh, I do have to use $P$ and other set-theoretic notations here... Currently learning set theory :)

Comment: @LucasShin Ah well. :P